# Conditional joint density functions

Tags: probability, density-function

Lets say I have $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, as my continuous probability density function.

I want the $\Bbb P(0<y<1 \mid x=2 )$. I'm going to take the plane $x=2$ and intersect it with $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, get a line/curve that is a continuous probability density function in terms of $y$.

Then I will integrate using the limits I want, wrt to $y$.
Why is this wrong?

I don't want to use $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = f_{Y,X}(y,x)/f_X(x)$, since I don't like how at the end we can plug in a single value for $x$, in a density function.

Thank you

Comment: The problem is that $f(2,y)$ is not necessarily a pdf since it need not integrate to $1$. To ensure you have a density you must *normalize* which is done by dividing $f(2,y)$ by $f_X(2)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(2,y)\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: Amazing and simple!!  I shouldn't have assumed intersecting curves of a pdf are pdfs.  Thank you so much,